# having trouble with ternary operators

Tags: java, eclipse

I was wandering how to make custom classes that can be used through out all of java eclipse. For example if you make any basic program you can call pre determined classes, like you can just type Math.abs(x); instead of having to go out of your way and typing

```
if (x<0) x = x * -1;
else x = x;
```

I would like to design my own custom classes for basic functions that I use a lot that i can use I in any program regardless of if they are in the same project or not.

Comment: I'm not sure how this relates to ternary operators, but you can use static methods and do `Math.abs(x)` in Java already, or define an abstract class with helper methods and extend that and just call the function. You can create a JAR with all the functions and then store it as a library for importing across projects.

Comment: ahh that was for another question that i researched some more and answered my self

Answer (score 0):

> custom classes that can be used through out all of java eclipse...

you can do that with any class as soon as you import that and define the right visibility for its data....

```
class MyRandom{


    public static int MultiplybyTwo(int number){
        return number * 2;
    }

    public static int DividebyTwo(int number){
        return number / 2;
    }

}



import MyRandom;

class Test{

    public static void main(string[] args){
        int x = MyRandom.MultiplyByThow(9);
        System.out.println("the result is: " + x);
    }
}
```

---

on the other hand, this makes no sense:

```
else x=x;
```

Comment: also if i am just importing classes is there a way I could set it up like using *. example import java.io.*;

Comment: using *. don't know why it didnt put that in the comment